# How to learn angular.js with mvc 4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs

I am to write my application with mvc 4 and angular.js
But I am unable to work with even I am not finding any good sources that teaches a combination of both.
I need to learn every thing how to bind models at view and how to upgrade models on button click and iteration and check box kind of changes.

Please suggest me what is the right approach and if there any good book and source available.

Comment: Look at this. This is work in progress but seems promising http://henriquat.re/

Answer (score 4):

there are lot's of tutorial about that, take a look at these:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gtFcNPLiCmA

http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechEd/Australia/2013/DEV331

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/cc6c9c5f-2846-4822-899f-a6c295cd4f2b

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/5af151b2-9ed2-4809-bfe8-27566bfe7d83

http://www.asp.net/single-page-application/overview/templates/breezeangular-template